# Javascript exception in robotframework

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I used this below code in robot framework to click the element 
**Execute Javascript           document.getElementsByClassName("kt-radio")[2].click();**
 javascript error:Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

And I used the below code
**Execute JavaScript         document.evaluate("//input[@id='1']/following-sibling::span",document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.click();**

javascript error:Cannot read property 'click' of null

The application am using to automate was built on Angular, can anyone help me to fix this because (my organisation wants to use only robot framework). Thanks in advance

Comment: The element locator is incorrect - `getElementsByClassName("kt-radio")` doesn't match anything - returns `undefined`, and the error says it.

Comment: @TodorMinakov Thank you for your reply. If you know how to use angularjs library in robot framework means can you help me out